# MySQL procedure is not executing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

This is my procedure

```
  DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE GET_CHECK_COURSES(IN distid int, IN `accescodeString` TEXT)
   BEGIN


 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accesstmp (
`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`accesscode` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 @query = "INSERT INTO accesstmp (`accesscode`) VALUES ('",accescodeString,"')";

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  @query1 = "SELECT 
  cde.code_status,
  co.course_code,
  co.course_name,
  u.organization,
  u1.email as licencinguser,
  cul.status,
  cul.learning_completion_date
  FROM cdp_access_codes as cde
  LEFT JOIN cdp_course as co ON cde.course_id = co.course_id
  LEFT JOIN cdp_user as u ON u.user_id = cde.licensing_user_id
  LEFT JOIN cdp_user as u1 ON u1.user_id = cde.user_id
  LEFT JOIN cdp_accesscode_courses as cac ON cac.code_id = cde.code_id
  LEFT JOIN cdp_user_licenses as cul ON cul.user_license_id = cac.course_subscription_id
  JOIN accesstmp as act ON act.accesscode = cde.access_code
  WHERE
  cde.distributor_user_id = $distributorId
  GROUP BY cde.access_code";


  PREPARE stmt2 FROM @query1;
  EXECUTE stmt2;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;



  END //
  DELIMITER ;
```

But when I executing this I got an syntax error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@query = "INSERT INTO accesstmp (`accesscode`) VALUES ('",accescodeString,"')"; ' at line 10

My parameters are like this param value distid = 24 and accescodeString is a strinh "mmmm, ssss, eeee"

Comment: I don't see it necessary to use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in `INSERT`. `$distributorId` variable should be one input parameter. Use [13.7.4 SET Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html) to assign the [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) (`\`@query\``) used.  Use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `concat` and `set` to local variables like `@variable`:

```
set @query = concat("INSERT INTO accesstmp (`accesscode`) VALUES ('",accescodeString,"')");


-- ...

set @query1 = "SELECT ...
```